# Cannot get image descriptors when creating a ViewPart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm not able to get image descriptors when creating a new ViewPart. Debugging the code I saw that I cannot get the Bundle for my plugin.

The code is the following:

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart {
 ...
 public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(MyPlugin.ID);
    // The bundle is null at this point but is not null in other
    // classes of my code
 }
}
```

When I try to get the `Bundle`, it is null at this point. What I don't understand is that the code works in other parts of my code.

Why I cannot get the bundle at this point?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. E.g. Are you sure about the id? Are you sure the bundle is activated?

Comment: Yes, the same line works in other parts of the code, so my guess is that the bundle is not active in that moment, or something like that, but I don't know how to check it...

Comment: You can check it using the OSGi console. Start the application with the `-console` option and use the `ss` command...